# Whatsapp Web QR code Scanning using Appium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

I have a company in-built web application that behaves similar to WhatsApp web. I need to link/scan using QR code of WhatsApp mobile application with company inbuilt web application using Appium with Java.

There is NO API information regarding QR code scanning in WhatsApp documentation which is causing trouble. There is documentation regarding APIs for WhatsApp business but not for normal WhatsApp.

I hope the above info is clear but let me be more clear as below.

> A is a web application that has a QR code to scan

> B is the WhatsApp Mobile application

Now I need to automate that using B application I should scan the QR code showing on A application using **Appium with Java.**

Could someone help with some suggestions or examples would be a great favor, please?

**Note:** There is NO API information regarding QR code scanning in WhatsApp documentation and also a screenshot of the QR code option also doesn’t exist in WhatsApp linked device option which is causing trouble. There is documentation regarding APIs for WhatsApp business but not for normal WhatsApp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this recently by requesting that Dev add an attribute to the QR code element that Appium could extract and run with. You aren't testing the QR code but the flow the QR code allows. You can manually run the QR code tests with each release and let automation handle the rest of the flow/regression.